# Multivariate Linear Regression - Unexpected Sign of Coefficient - Mitigation Options via different models

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, vector-autoregression, linear

I am trying to forecast corporate earnings for a number of companies using multivariate linear regression. As independent variables I am using:

- "Oil Price Change"
- "GDP Growth"
- "Exchange Rate Change".

The problem that I am facing is that the "Oil Price Change" coefficient is positive, which implies that corporate earnings on average increase when oil price increases.

But, oil, being an input/cost in the production process should be having a negative sign in its coefficient. (especially if there are not many oil companies in my sample to argue that increased profitability comes from them).

It seems that the effect of "Oil price changes" is "masked" (if i can use this term) by the increase in GDP. For example, an increase in GDP will drive both the corporate earnings higher and the oil price higher (especially if there is global GDP growth) and because of this my model assigns a positive value to the oil coefficient.

**My question:**

What alternative type of models can I use to capture this kind of "network/sequence effect"? i.e. Oil reduces costs and reduced costs push earnings higher?

I am thinking of VAR models but I would like to understand first what my options are.